# Not able to see time zone, place or geolocation of any tweets

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, spark-streaming, azure-stream-analytics

I am following two tutorials right now and both are up and running and I've gotten plenty of tweets/sentiment scores from them:

1) **Twitter Stream Analytics on Azure** https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-twitter-sentiment-analysis-trends/

2) **Twitter Analysis with Spark Streaming**http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/3/exercises/realtime-processing-with-spark-streaming.html

I am using the free oauth tool provided from apps.twitter.com.

**Problem**
I've tried getPlace, getGeoLocation in the Spark Streaming app and every tweet I get has a null value for those two fields. I have tried filtering for tweets that only have values for getPlace, get GeoLocation and I get null for both (I ran the app for almost 20 minutes).

I've also tried getting TimeZone in the Azure app (so I can get some sort of geography data) and even then I kept getting null values for TimeZone.

**Possible Obstacles**
1) Does the free twitter api filter out the place/geoLocation information so I end up buying a subscription to a better api?

2) Do I need to explicitly search for tweets that have geoLocation/Places? Rather than getting all tweets and then filtering out ones that have geoLocation/Places? If so, can I execute this search in Spark Streaming?This is the code that I have in Spark Streaming:

```
val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters) 
val hashTags = stream.map(status => Tweet(status.getPlace().getName(), classifyTweet(status.getText())))
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used the free Twitter api to get locations and publish them on a a map on PowerBi. So you can rule out the first obstacle.

One thing to note is that location field is only available if the client specifically allows the application to have location, which renders it quite rare to be found. The ratio for data with location in my sample data was about 8%.

Don't have an answer for spark side, just wanted to help you rule out the first possibility.

Hope this helps.